# Pandas Read CSV in django view not working

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-templates

What I'm trying to do is, when user uploaded the CSV file. I'm trying to do functionalities in pandas.

**Django template**

```
<form action="{% url 'upload-timeslot' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

**My view**

```
def bulk_timeslot_upload(request):
    if request.FILES:
        import pandas as pd
        csv = request.FILES['fileToUpload']
        data = pd.read_csv(csv)
        print(data)
    return render(request, 'bulk-timeslot.html')
```

when i tried to read csv, running server getting exited. If I import pandas globally, server not even running.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and what helped me was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59438263/2142093). (More info in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/uploads/#custom-upload-handlers))

In `views.py`

```
def import_csv(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImportFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            # the temporary_file_path() shows Dask where to find the file
            df_in = dd.read_csv(request.FILES['file_name'].temporary_file_path())
```

in `settings.py`

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = ['django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',]
```

Answer (score -1):

actually the read_csv() takes in file, but ur request.FILES['fileToUpload'] is the memorybuffer. So, 2 possible ways are either save the csv file in ur system and then read it by passing the whole path, or use :

```
  def bulk_timeslot_upload(request):
    if request.FILES:
       import pandas as pd
       csv = request.FILES['fileToUpload']
       data = pd.read_csv(csv.read())
       print(data)
  return render(request, 'bulk-timeslot.html')
```

Comment: this is not working. I don't know, why running server getting stopped. If its error, it will show the error.

Comment: django server getting stopped!??

Comment: yeah it stopped, when i call this function