# Insert data in model from json in django

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-views

My Model:

```
class Post_Data(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I need to insert the json data inside the model which will be passed in the form of "file" in postman.

I tried:

```
    def post(self, request):
        json_file = request.FILES['json_file']
        with open(json_file) as f:
            json_data = json.loads(f)
            a = Post_data(data=json_data)
            a.save()
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Django [Fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures) for prepopulating of data. Additionally using JsonField()  might be useful to you.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class ......
    data = JSONField()
```

Comment: I am trying to send data through file i.e by requesting file in request and than storing in model. @ DARK_C0D3R

Comment: can you print type and data of json_data

Comment: print(type(json_data))

Comment: i'm getting invalid file: <InMemoryUploadedFile: FILENAME> error when i'm uploading file.

Comment: you might be reading it from some buffer, might be this is useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/59438263/8865579